# GridBagLayout not lining up

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have 5 `JPanels` lined up vertically. Each `JPanel` is filled with the same elements, but different values (`JPanel`, `JButton`, `JLabel`). I want them to look like this:

```
Panel   Button   Label
Panel   Button   Label
```

Buts it's turning out like this

```
Panel   Button   Label
Panel Button     Label
```

The spacing is a little off, but the code is exactly the same for each container. How can I fix this?

```
public class AnswerChoice extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private AnswerButton button;
    private JLabel answerLabel;

    public AnswerChoice(String imageURL) {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        button = new AnswerButton(imageURL);
        answerLabel = new JLabel();
        answerLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 32));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.2;
        add(panel, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 30);
        add(button, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.weightx = 0.8;
        add(answerLabel, gbc);
    }

}
```

The `JLabel` does have text in it but I set it somewhere else.

Comment: You probably want `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_LEADING;`.  The anchor field determines the placement of a component within its cell.

Comment: It seems a 3 column table would be better suited to displaying the data. Different `GridBagLayout` instances in different panels cannot be made to align together!

Comment: Can I give proportional spacing in a table? I used the `GridBagLayout` so I could use the 0.2 and 0.8 weights

Comment: @kneedhelp, `Can I give proportional spacing` - I was just editing my answer when you made that comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the code is exactly the same for each container.

The layout is done independently for each container based on the components added to the containter. So the size of each component on the container matters. Each container doesn't know that you have 4 other containers.

> I have 5 JPanels lined up vertically.

So then you need to create a single panel using a GridBagLayout and add all 15 components to that panel. Then all 3 columns will be sized based on the components in each of the 5 rows.

Or I see in your logic that you try to assign relative sizes to each of the 3 components as .2, 0, .8. In this case you could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) on each of the panels. Using the `Relative Layout` you would display the button at its preferred size and then use 0.2f and 0.8f as the contraints for the panel and label respectively.

Comment: That's an awesome layout, just what I was looking for! Thanks!